# How to insert a graphic/figure into LaTeX from Word?

Tags: graphics, eps, epstopdf

I am trying to include a figure into LaTeX from a paper originally created using MS Word. I have already converted all the text/equations into LaTeX but I can't figure out how to get the figures over without re-drawing them using LaTeX code (which I do not want to do). The image is a plain box (like a `tabular`) one row by 7 columns with numbers inside each cell. Then I inserted arrows of varying length above and below the box (several short ones and one much longer).

I am trying to use the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package with the `\includegraphics` command.

I copied the figure (box and arrows) from my original article into a blank Word doc. The figure only takes up the first 4 or 5 lines of the blank document. I then selected/highlighted the image and printed the selection using 'PDFCreator'. This allowed me to save the image as a `.eps` file. I then copied and pasted the eps file into the folder where all my `.tex` files are saved.

When I compile the document using `pdftexify` there is a blank space where the image should be. In the console I get the following message when I compile the document:

```
[27] <Fig3-eps-converted-to.pdf, id =105, 391.4625pt x 74.2774pt>
<use Fig3-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Overfull \hbox 1.46153pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 511--516
[]
```

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}

%Text

\includegraphics{fig3.eps}

%text

\end{document}
```

I have read the sections on graphics in 'LaTeX: A Document Preparation System' and 'The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e' but I still can't figure this out. Should I maybe use a PNG image since it is a pretty basic figure? Any advice on how to properly transfer images from a word doc to .eps format and/or how to get those `.eps` files into LaTeX properly would be a huge help.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the `eps` file. Try opening it in a viewer; what do you see?

Comment: When I double click the desired eps file it opens Ghostscript or my GSView. The image is a full page with the figure at the top 1/6 of the page.

Comment: You can (probably) save a figure from Word as a pdf, then crop it with pdfcrop before inserting it in your LaTeX document.

Comment: In GSView, there should be an menu option to choose the size of the viewing window. It may be set to A4 or Letter by default. Try changing this to BBox. How much white space is left around the image?

Comment: There is no BBox option in the dropdown 'media' menu. I tried to type BBox in the 'user defined' media. I typed BBox into the width and height options but that did not get my figure into the Bounding box. THe bounding box is slightly below my figure in GSView and I don't know how to move the bounding box or my figure.

Comment: Can you make the `eps` file available for download?

Comment: @ian I could not figure out how to upload files onto this page/question. I found your email address through your profile so I sent you an email with the files attached.

Comment: @EthanBolker Better yet, [there are tools](http://superuser.com/a/169462/160871) to extract images from PDF directly.  Alternative workflow: Copy image from within Word, paste into imgur, download raw image.

Comment: @ian Thank you so much Ian! Reconfiguring the parameters on the bounding box worked perfectly. I used notepad so the BB code was on the first line as opposed to the second but that is probably because I used notepad. Everything came up roses in my Tex document ... Thanks Again

Answer (score 7):

This problem is almost certainly caused by an incorrect bounding box in the eps file. One way to fix this is to rename your file to 'Fig3.ps' and in the terminal do

```
ps2eps --ignoreBB Fig3.ps
```

Alternatively, you can fix the bounding box yourself. Open the `eps` file in your favourite text editor. The second line will be something like

```
%%BoundingBox: A B C D
```

where `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are numbers. In order, these set the left, lower, right and upper edges of the image. Changing these numbers will adjust the bounding box. For example, increasing `A` crops the left side. Set the numbers in the third line (`HiResBoundingBox`) to the same values, save the file and refresh it in your viewer to see the effect. A bit of trial and error usually does the trick.